# videos doesn't work in exoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am beginner in android , i have a problem when using ExoPlayer . my ExoPlayer works well when using mp3 format but the problem appear when using mp4 or trying to play video in Exoplayer it doesn't show any thing

**here's my activity**

in this activity i initiallize mediaSession and initialize mediaPlayer for exoplayer

```html
package com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp.recipeContents.steps;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

public class stepDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  ExoPlayer.EventListener {
    private SimpleExoPlayer mExoPlayer;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView mPlayerView;
    private static MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;
    private PlaybackStateCompat.Builder mStateBuilder;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private static final String TAG = stepDetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_step_detail);

        steps myrecipes = (steps) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("stepDetails");

        mPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
        initializeMediaSession();
        initializePlayer(Uri.parse("https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/April/58ffd9cb_4-press-crumbs-in-pie-plate-creampie/4-press-crumbs-in-pie-plate-creampie.mp4"));

    }
    private void initializePlayer(Uri mediaUri) {
        if (mExoPlayer == null) {
            // Create an instance of the ExoPlayer.
           TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
            mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
            mPlayerView.setPlayer(mExoPlayer);

            // Set the ExoPlayer.EventListener to this activity.
            mExoPlayer.addListener(this);

            // Prepare the MediaSource.
            String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "Bakingapp");
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                    this, userAgent), new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
            mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the Media Session to be enabled with media buttons, transport controls, callbacks
     * and media controller.
     */
    private void initializeMediaSession() {

        // Create a MediaSessionCompat.
        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, TAG);

        // Enable callbacks from MediaButtons and TransportControls.
        mMediaSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                        MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        // Do not let MediaButtons restart the player when the app is not visible.
        mMediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(null);

        // Set an initial PlaybackState with ACTION_PLAY, so media buttons can start the player.
        mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);

        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());


        // MySessionCallback has methods that handle callbacks from a media controller.
        mMediaSession.setCallback(new MySessionCallback());

        // Start the Media Session since the activity is active.
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        if((playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) && playWhenReady){
            mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING,
                    mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);
        } else if((playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY)){
            mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED,
                    mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);
        }
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

    }

    /**
     * Media Session Callbacks, where all external clients control the player.
     */
    private class MySessionCallback extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            mExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**here's the xml layout for exoplayer**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp.stepDetailActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        >
    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

the ExtractorMediaSource should work for the mp4

```
    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "Bakingapp");
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, defaultDataSourceFactory,new
            DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
    mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```